# Is it possible to do case-insensitive search on Keys/Fields in MongoDB? with Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

For example a way to treat or detect a field "productionYear" in DB against "productionyear".
So can I do caseinsentive search on both fields and values?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `$$ROOT` document into array of k-v tuples with `$objectToArray` and `$filter` with `$toLower` for k(i.e. field name). `$match` with `$size` > 0 to find for at least one match.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
            },
            "as": "kv",
            "cond": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    {
                      $toLower: "$$kv.k"
                    },
                    "productionyear"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    1,
                    "$$kv.v"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      0
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/veQ920oCgXn)

---

Please note that the above approach might not benefit from indexes. Instead, it is suggest to standardize the field name.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "productionYear": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$productionYear",
          "$productionyear"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "productionyear"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XG9l0rpduoq)